# Need to reboot to correctly connect to Epson printer/scanner (via usb)

Tags: usb, 22.04, scanner

When I try to connect my Epson XP-2100 via USB, simple-scan detects it as expected. However, actually scanning a document hangs for a bit and then says "Unable to connect to scanner". If I reboot, the problem goes away.

When I run `scanimage -L` before the reboot, the output is like this:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `imagescan:esci:usb:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0' is a EPSON XP-2100_Series
```

After the reboot, it looks like this:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epsonds:libusb:001:006' is a Epson EW-052A Series ESC/I-2
device `imagescan:esci:usb:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0' is a EPSON XP-2100_Series
```

In dmesg I can see this (this is after the reboot, when the scanner works):

```
[   18.487612] kauditd_printk_skb: 62 callbacks suppressed
[   18.487613] audit: type=1400 audit(1664623627.532:74): apparmor="DENIED" oper
ation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" capability=12  c
apname="net_admin"
[   20.037340] usblp2: removed
[   20.046982] usblp 1-6:1.1: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 1 alt 0
 proto 2 vid 0x04B8 pid 0x114E
[   20.505173] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control
 rx/tx
```

After the reboot, simple-scan scans images successfully.

Is there a way to either do whatever it does on boot to get the "epsonds" device to appear, or better yet get this to happen when I plug the printer in?

The one thing I have tried is `sudo rmmod usblp;sudo modprobe usblp`, but I can't think of anything else.

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I think I have had this problem on an earlier version as well.

Comment: You do not say whether either device (imagescan or epsonds) gives scanning.

Comment: @brian_p I believe the epsonds device does.

Comment: Maybe this documentation will help you to find out how to bypass your printer getting denied by AppArmor: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor